# apache2.conf need allow to acces just one file

Tags: apache

Here is my current apache2.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1 ::1
    Allow from localhost
    Allow from 10
    Satisfy Any
```

But I want allow access to a one file http://my_server_ip/handl.php What I should do?

Comment: you can put that in a directory..

Comment: If you understood configuration upper access to my host possible just from localhost.. But I want open access just for a single file http://my_server_ip/handl.php